# Разница между getDefaultSharedPreferences и getSharedPreferences

Tags: android, java

два вопроса:

1. какая разница между этими двумя методами, для каких целей существует каждый из них ?
2. имеется две Активити - главная, где получен `getDefaultSharedPreferences`, и `PreferenceActivity`. почему `PreferenceActivity` нормально работает только с `getDefaultSharedPreferences`? не особо понимаю КАК `PrefsActivity` знает куда ей класть новые выставленные значения. ведь объект `SharedPreferences` я создаю в гланой активити, и ничего не передаю в `PreferenceActivity`.

**ЗЫ** немного почитав исходники метода `getDefaultSharedPreferences`, понял как он создаёт файл: `context.getPackageName() + "_preferences"`. стало быть `PreferenceActivity` использует ту же самую строку для определения файл куда класть сохранённые значения. я прав?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Можно создать поименованные преференсы и вообще у приложения их может быть несколько. `getDefaultSharedPreferences` существует для работы с префами по умолчанию. В **ЗЫ** вы все правильно написали. Преференсы по умолчанию это файл типа `mypackage_preferences.xml`
2. В `PreferenceActivity` можно открыть любой преференс задав его имя: `getPreferenceManager().setSharedPreferencesName("MyPrefs");` Если имя не задано то он работает с префами по умолчанию.

Comment: спасибо, то что надо.